# ssrs subreport page break not working

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

The ssrs subreport page break is not working.

[image: Screenshot of page break not working]

How can I get ssrs sub report page break ? Thanks.

i.e. `Reports -> properties -> pagebreak` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put a subreport in a **Rectangle** and let the rectangle control the page break.

[image]

I'm not sure where you want to put your page break. Judging by your picture and arrow, it seems you're concerned with keeping the data of one subreport together **without** breaking.

This would be the **KeepTogether** property of the subreport object. Set it to TRUE so it will add a page break rather than break up a subreport instance.

[image]

Comment: it's not necessary to put a subreport into rectangle. The same result can be achieved by placing a rectangle before subreport.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but in case someone has same problem than me, I figured out another reason why a page break is not applied for at beginning of a sub report (also available for any control like Tablix, Textbox,...).

I have one rectangle containing a subreport. I want that subreport starting by a PageBreak.

The rectangle is then at the location Top = 0cm.
If I changed the Top=0.001cm => the page break is applied :)
(ok with 0.001cm but not with 0.0001cm....so close but not too close for SSRS apparently :))

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason this can happen is if the subreport is contained within a merged cell. Once I modified the main report in a way where the subreport was contained within a single unmerged cell, the page breaks in the subreport worked as expected.